# How to get one iframe to close after opening another iframe using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have 2 iframes on a careers page for a site, the client has supplied me to iframes from which their open positions populate from. I have it set up to where when you click on a link or an image, the iframes open and close via .toggle();
Here is my code:

```
<div class="OpenPositions-left">
    <div class="position-city">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_field('view_positions_link_left'); ?>"    class="ny-positions"><?php the_field('position_city_left'); ?></a></h2>
</div>
<a href="<?php the_field('view_positions_link_left'); ?>" class="ny-positions">
    <img src="<?php the_field('open_positions_left'); ?>" />
</a>
<a href="<?php the_field('view_positions_link_left'); ?>" class="ny-positions"><?php the_field('view_positions_left'); ?></a>
</div><!-- end of open positions left -->
<div class="OpenPositions-right">
<div class="position-cityRight">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_field('view_positions_link_right'); ?>"     class="rus-positions"><?php the_field('position_city_right'); ?></a></h2>
    </div>  
     <a href="<?php the_field('view_positions_link_right'); ?>" class="rus-positions">
    <img src="<?php the_field('open_positions_right'); ?>" />
    </a>
    <a href="<?php the_field('view_positions_link_right'); ?>" class="rus-positions"><?php the_field('view_positions_right'); ?></a>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
    <div id="iframeHeightDiv" name="" align="center" class="newyork-iframe openjobs-container">
     <iframe id="inlineframe" name=""src="" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin">   </iframe>
    </div><!-- end of iframe -->
    <div id="hr" class="rushr openjobs-container">
    <script src="second-ifrmae.php"></script>
</div><!-- end of bamboohr -->
</div><!-- end of OpenPositions -->

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('div.openjobs-container').each(function() {
        var $OpenJobs = $(this);    
        $('openjobs-container', $OpenJobs).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $div = $(div.'openjobs-container').not($div).hide();
            return false;
        });

    });

});



</script>
```

Code not working any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide the generated HTML, not the PHP version.

Comment: check your console for errors will show you there is a syntax problem

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in this block of code:

```
$('openjobs-container', $OpenJobs).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $div = $(div.'openjobs-container').not($div).hide();
    return false;
});
```

The selector in this line of code:

```
$div = $(div.'openjobs-container').not($div).hide();
```

Ought to be a string:

```
$div = $('div.openjobs-container').not($div).hide();
```